# Abstract Function of a Function

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, series-expansion

I am trying to write a function $V(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} p^iV_i(x)$ in that abstract form. The idea is eventually I need to plug this in for a Taylor Expansion of terms of $\ln\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\right)$ and then separate by like terms of p powers. When I try and define this as an abstract function, though, and take the partial with respect to x, Mathematica returns 0 rather than treating it as an abstract partial derivative to simplify. Furthermore, I can't figure out how to get Mathematica to separate by powers of $p^i$.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: if you define `V` with `n` as an argument, `ClearAll[V, v, p, x, n]; V[n_Integer, x_] := Sum[ p^i v[i][x], {i, 1, n}];` then
`D[V[3, x], x]` gives `p Derivative[1][v[1]][x] + p^2 Derivative[1][v[2]][x] + 
 p^3 Derivative[1][v[3]][x]`.  And  `MonomialList[V[3, x]]`  or `Cases[V[3, x], p^_.  stuff___]`  give  `{p^3 v[3][x], p^2 v[2][x], p v[1][x]}` .  Is this what you need?

Comment: The result is very close to what I want but not exactly. Cases is treating terms that Mathematica writes as (-1+p)*STUFF + p*STUFF2 as two separate terms. MonomialList doesn't seem to work. Also, for some reason when I do `Derivative[0,1]v[n][x,t]`, for the case of `v[0][x,t]:=x`, it treats it as `x^(0,1)` rather than 0. Any idea why this is the case? Otherwise, the solution works great.

Comment: does this fix the issue you mention: `v[0][x_, t_] := x;
Derivative[0, 1]@v[0][x, t]`?

Comment: .. and i think you need  `Collect[V[3, x], p]`  not `Cases[V[3, x], p^_. stuff___]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works well.